# How to validate captcha within an online form

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, captcha

My job is to create a form for a competition and collect the data.
This data will be collected by a company that we use to send e-mails (think Mail chimp).
This company (email vision through their online software "campaign commander") has generated the form below.
as you can see it does not validate captcha.
What code do I need to make it validate captcha without leaving the form?
The site was developed in PHP.
Thank you for your help.
and God bless us.
Julian P.

```
                <html>
                <head>
                <title>Webform</title>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
                <script language="javascript">
                function isInteger(input,fieldName){
                var i;
                for(i=0;i<input.value.length;i++){
                var c=input.value.charAt(i);
                if(((c<'0')||(c>'9'))){
                alert('The number in '+fieldName+' is not valid.');
                input.focus();
                return false;
                }}
                return true;
                }
                var dtCh='/';
                var minYear=1900;
                var maxYear=2100;
                function isValidInteger(s){
                var i;
                for(i=0;i<s.length;i++){
                var c=s.charAt(i);
                if(((c<'0')||(c>'9'))) return false;
                }
                return true;
                }
                function stripCharsInBag(s,bag){
                var i;
                var returnString='';
                for(i=0;i<s.length;i++){
                var c=s.charAt(i);
                if(bag.indexOf(c)==-1) returnString+=c;
                }
                return returnString;
                }
                function daysInFebruary(year){
                return(((year%4==0)&&((!(year % 100 == 0))||(year%400==0)))?29:28);
                }
                function DaysArray(n){
                for(var i=1;i<=n;i++){
                this[i]=31;
                if(i==4||i==6||i==9||i==11){this[i]=30;}
                if(i==2){this[i]=29;}
                }
                return this;
                }
                function isDateOK(dtStr){
                if(dtStr=='') return true;
                var daysInMonth=DaysArray(12);
                var pos1=dtStr.indexOf(dtCh);
                var pos2=dtStr.indexOf(dtCh,pos1+1);
                var strDay=dtStr.substring(0,pos1);
                var strMonth=dtStr.substring(pos1+1,pos2);
                var strYear=dtStr.substring(pos2+1);
                strYr=strYear;
                if(strDay.charAt(0)=='0'&&strDay.length>1) strDay=strDay.substring(1);
                if(strMonth.charAt(0)=='0'&&strMonth.length>1) strMonth=strMonth.substring(1);
                for(var i=1;i<=3;i++){
                if(strYr.charAt(0)=='0'&&strYr.length>1) strYr=strYr.substring(1);
                }
                month=parseInt(strMonth);
                day=parseInt(strDay);
                year=parseInt(strYr);
                if(pos1==-1||pos2==-1){
                alert('The date format should be : dd/mm/yyyy.');
                return false;
                }
                if(strMonth.length<1||month<1||month>12){
                alert('Please enter a valid month.');
                return false;
                }
                if(strDay.length<1||day<1||day>31||(month==2&&day>daysInFebruary(year))||day>daysInMonth[month]){
                alert('Please enter a valid day.');
                return false;
                }
                if(strYear.length!=4||year==0||year<minYear||year>maxYear){
                alert('Please enter a valid 4 digit year between '+minYear+' and '+maxYear+'.');
                return false;
                }
                if(dtStr.indexOf(dtCh,pos2+1)!=-1||isValidInteger(stripCharsInBag(dtStr,dtCh))==false){
                alert('Please enter a valid date.');
                return false;
                }
                return true;
                }
                function modifyDateFormat(dt){
                var valuesTable=dt.value.split(dtCh);
                dt.value=valuesTable[1]+dtCh+valuesTable[0]+dtCh+valuesTable[2];
                }
                function isEmail(emailAddress){
                emailAddressValue=emailAddress.value.toLowerCase();
                var countryTLDs=/^(ac|ad|ae|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|as|at|au|aw|ax|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cat|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|cr|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gd|ge|gf|gg|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|im|in|io|iq|ir|is|it|je|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|me|mg|mh|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|nc|ne|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nu|nz|om|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|rs|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|um|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)$/;
                var gTLDs=/^(aero|asia|biz|cat|com|coop|edu|geo|gov|info|int|jobs|mil|mobi|museum|name|net|org|post|pro|tel|travel)$/;
                var basicAddress=/^(.+)@(.+)$/;
                var specialChars='\\(\\)><@,;:\\\\\\\"\\.\\[\\]';
                var validChars='\[^\\s'+specialChars+'\]';
                var validCharset='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzöå0123456789\'-_.+';
                var quotedUser='(\"[^\"]*\")';
                var atom=validChars+'+';
                var word='('+atom+'|'+quotedUser+')';
                var validUser=new RegExp('^'+word+'(\.'+word+')*$');
                var symDomain=new RegExp('^'+atom+'(\.'+atom+')*$');
                var matchArray=emailAddressValue.match(basicAddress);
                if(emailAddress.value==''||emailAddress==null){
                return true;
                }
                if(matchArray==null){
                alert('The Email address doesn\'t seem to be correct,\nplease check syntax.');
                emailAddress.focus();
                return false;
                }else{
                var user=matchArray[1];
                var domain=matchArray[2];
                for(i=0;i<user.length;i++){
                if(validCharset.indexOf(user.charAt(i))==-1){
                alert('The Email address contains invalid characters,\nplease check the username.');
                emailAddress.focus();
                return false;
                }
                }
                for(i=0;i<domain.length;i++){
                if(validCharset.indexOf(domain.charAt(i))==-1){
                alert('The Email address contains invalid characters,\nplease check the domain.');
                emailAddress.focus();
                return false;
                }
                }
                if(user.match(validUser)==null){
                alert('The Email address doesn\'t seem to be correct,\nplease check the username.');
                emailAddress.focus();
                return false;
                }
                var atomPat=new RegExp('^'+atom+'$');
                var domArr=domain.split('.');
                var len=domArr.length;
                for(i=0;i<len;i++){
                if(domArr[i].search(atomPat)==-1){
                alert('The Email address doesn\'t seem to be correct,\nplease check the domain name.');
                emailAddress.focus();
                return false;
                }
                }
                if((domArr[domArr.length-1].length==2)&&(domArr[domArr.length-1].search(countryTLDs)==-1)){
                alert('The Email address doesn\'t seem to be correct,\nplease check domain suffix.');
                emailAddress.focus();
                return false;
                }
                if((domArr[domArr.length-1].length>2)&&(domArr[domArr.length-1].search(gTLDs)==-1)){
                alert('The Email address doesn\'t seem to be correct,\nplease check domain suffix.');
                emailAddress.focus();
                return false;
                }
                if((domArr[domArr.length-1].length<2)||(domArr[domArr.length-1].length>6)){
                alert('The Email address doesn\'t seem to be correct,\nplease check domain suffix.');
                emailAddress.focus();
                return false;
                }
                if(len<2){
                alert('The Email address doesn\'t seem to be correct,\nplease check missing hostname.');
                emailAddress.focus();
                return false;
                }
                }
                return true;
                }
                function mandatoryCheckBox(checkBox,fieldName){
                var nbcheck=0;
                if(checkBox.length==undefined){
                if(checkBox.checked){ nbcheck++; }
                }else{
                for (counter=0;counter<checkBox.length;counter++){
                if(checkBox[counter].checked){ nbcheck++; }
                }
                }
                if(nbcheck==0){
                alert('Please select your '+fieldName+'.');
                return false;
                }
                return true;
                }
                function mandatoryDropDown(dropDown,fieldName){
                if(dropDown.options[dropDown.options.selectedIndex].value == ""){
                alert('Please select your '+fieldName+'.');
                dropDown.focus();
                return false;
                }
                return true;
                }
                String.prototype.trim = function() { return this.replace(/^\s*(\b.*\b|)\s*$/, "$1");    }
                function mandatoryText(input,fieldName){
                if(input.value.trim()==''||input==null){
                alert('Please enter your '+fieldName+'.');
                input.focus();
                return false;
                } else {
                return true;
                }
                }
                function validForm(){
                if(!mandatoryText(document.getElementById('FIRSTNAME_FIELD'), 'First name')) return;
                if(!mandatoryText(document.getElementById('LASTNAME_FIELD'), 'Surname')) return;
                if(!mandatoryText(document.getElementById('DATEOFBIRTH_FIELD'), 'Date of birth')) return;
                if(!isDateOK(document.getElementById('DATEOFBIRTH_FIELD').value)) return;
                if(!mandatoryText(document.getElementById('EMAIL_FIELD'), 'Email')) return;
                if(!isEmail(document.getElementById('EMAIL_FIELD'))) return;
                if(!mandatoryText(document.getElementById('EMVCELLPHONE_FIELD'), 'Mobile')) return;
                if(!isInteger(document.getElementById('EMVCELLPHONE_FIELD'), 'Mobile')) return;
                if(!mandatoryDropDown(document.getElementById('STORE_NAME_FIELD'), 'Nearest shop')) return;
                if(!mandatoryCheckBox(document.getElementById('emvForm').OPTIN_FIELD, 'Opt in to marketing emails')) return;
                if(document.getElementById('DATEOFBIRTH_FIELD').value!='') modifyDateFormat(document.getElementById('DATEOFBIRTH_FIELD'));
                document.getElementById('emvForm').submit();
                if(document.getElementById('DATEOFBIRTH_FIELD').value!='') modifyDateFormat(document.getElementById('DATEOFBIRTH_FIELD'));
                }
                </script>
                </head>
                <body>
                <form name="emvForm" id="emvForm" action="http://tre.emv3.com/D2UTF8" method="POST" target="_top">
                <input type="hidden" name="emv_tag" value="876020001C384269" />
                <input type="hidden" name="emv_ref" value="EdX7CqkdLe_d8SA9MOPQNCffL0p6Hq3D-jmueKEyWsbQKbo" />
                <table>
                <tr>
                <td>
                First name
                </td>
                <td>
                <input type="text" id="FIRSTNAME_FIELD" name="FIRSTNAME_FIELD" value="" size="30" maxlength="64">
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>
                Surname
                </td>
                <td>
                <input type="text" id="LASTNAME_FIELD" name="LASTNAME_FIELD" value="" size="30" maxlength="64">
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>
                Date of birth
                </td>
                <td>
                <input type="text" id="DATEOFBIRTH_FIELD" name="DATEOFBIRTH_FIELD" value="" size="30" maxlength="64">
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>
                Email
                </td>
                <td>
                <input type="text" id="EMAIL_FIELD" name="EMAIL_FIELD" value="" size="30" maxlength="64">
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>
                Mobile
                </td>
                <td>
                <input type="text" id="EMVCELLPHONE_FIELD" name="EMVCELLPHONE_FIELD" value="" size="30" maxlength="64">
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>
                Nearest shop
                </td>
                <td>
                <select id="STORE_NAME_FIELD" name="STORE_NAME_FIELD">
                <option selected value=""></option>
                <option value="Aberdeen ">Aberdeen </option>
                <option value="Acton ">Acton </option>
                <option value="Aldgate ">Aldgate </option>
                <option value="Ashford ">Ashford </option>
                <option value="Aylesbury ">Aylesbury </option>
                <option value="Baker Street ">Baker Street </option>
                <option value="Balham ">Balham </option>
                <option value="Ballymena ">Ballymena </option>
                <option value="Barnet ">Barnet </option>
                <option value="Beckenham ">Beckenham </option>
                <option value="Belfast ">Belfast </option>
                <option value="Bethnal Green ">Bethnal Green </option>
                <option value="Bexleyheath ">Bexleyheath </option>
                <option value="Biggleswade ">Biggleswade </option>
                <option value="Birmingham ">Birmingham </option>
                <option value="Birmingham New Street ">Birmingham New Street </option>
                <option value="Bishopsgate ">Bishopsgate </option>
                <option value="Bond Street ">Bond Street </option>
                <option value="Bromley ">Bromley </option>
                <option value="Camberwell ">Camberwell </option>
                <option value="Cambridge ">Cambridge </option>
                <option value="Camden Town ">Camden Town </option>
                <option value="Chelmsford ">Chelmsford </option>
                <option value="Chelsea ">Chelsea </option>
                <option value="Cheltenham ">Cheltenham </option>
                <option value="Chester ">Chester </option>
                <option value="Chiswick ">Chiswick </option>
                <option value="Clacton-on-Sea ">Clacton-on-Sea </option>
                <option value="Clapham High Street ">Clapham High Street </option>
                <option value="Clapham Junction ">Clapham Junction </option>
                <option value="Colchester ">Colchester </option>
                <option value="Coleraine ">Coleraine </option>
                <option value="Covent Garden ">Covent Garden </option>
                <option value="Coventry ">Coventry </option>
                <option value="Cricklewood ">Cricklewood </option>
                <option value="Crouch End ">Crouch End </option>
                <option value="Croydon ">Croydon </option>
                <option value="Dalston ">Dalston </option>
                <option value="Ealing ">Ealing </option>
                <option value="Earls Court ">Earls Court </option>
                <option value="Edgware ">Edgware </option>
                <option value="Exeter ">Exeter </option>
                <option value="Farringdon ">Farringdon </option>
                <option value="Fleet Street ">Fleet Street </option>
                <option value="Fulham ">Fulham </option>
                <option value="Glasgow ">Glasgow </option>
                <option value="Godalming ">Godalming </option>
                <option value="Golders Green ">Golders Green </option>
                <option value="Guildford ">Guildford </option>
                <option value="Hackney ">Hackney </option>
                <option value="Hammersmith ">Hammersmith </option>
                <option value="Hampstead ">Hampstead </option>
                <option value="Highbury ">Highbury </option>
                <option value="Holborn ">Holborn </option>
                <option value="Ipswich ">Ipswich </option>
                <option value="Angel ">Angel </option>
                <option value="Kensington ">Kensington </option>
                <option value="Kentish Town ">Kentish Town </option>
                <option value="Kilburn ">Kilburn </option>
                <option value="Kings Lynn ">Kings Lynn </option>
                <option value="Kingston ">Kingston </option>
                <option value="Knightsbridge ">Knightsbridge </option>
                <option value="Leadenhall Market ">Leadenhall Market </option>
                <option value="Lewisham ">Lewisham </option>
                <option value="Lisburn ">Lisburn </option>
                <option value="Lincoln ">Lincoln </option>
                <option value="Londonderry ">Londonderry </option>
                <option value="Luton ">Luton </option>
                <option value="Maidenhead ">Maidenhead </option>
                <option value="Maidstone ">Maidstone </option>
                <option value="Mansion House ">Mansion House </option>
                <option value="Marble Arch ">Marble Arch </option>
                <option value="Marlow ">Marlow </option>
                <option value="Marylebone ">Marylebone </option>
                <option value="Mayfair ">Mayfair </option>
                <option value="Milton Keynes ">Milton Keynes </option>
                <option value="Muswell Hill ">Muswell Hill </option>
                <option value="Newbury ">Newbury </option>
                <option value="Northampton ">Northampton </option>
                <option value="Norwich ">Norwich </option>
                <option value="Notting Hill Gate ">Notting Hill Gate </option>
                <option value="Oxford ">Oxford </option>
                <option value="Peckham ">Peckham </option>
                <option value="Peterborough ">Peterborough </option>
                <option value="Pimlico ">Pimlico </option>
                <option value="Portobello ">Portobello </option>
                <option value="Putney ">Putney </option>
                <option value="Queensway ">Queensway </option>
                <option value="Reading ">Reading </option>
                <option value="Richmond ">Richmond </option>
                <option value="Romford ">Romford </option>
                <option value="Shepherds Bush ">Shepherds Bush </option>
                <option value="Slough ">Slough </option>
                <option value="Soho ">Soho </option>
                <option value="South Kensington ">South Kensington </option>
                <option value="Southend ">Southend </option>
                <option value="St Johns Wood ">St Johns Wood </option>
                <option value="Staines ">Staines </option>
                <option value="Streatham ">Streatham </option>
                <option value="Surbiton ">Surbiton </option>
                <option value="Sutton ">Sutton </option>
                <option value="Swiss Cottage ">Swiss Cottage </option>
                <option value="Sydenham ">Sydenham </option>
                <option value="Tooting ">Tooting </option>
                <option value="Tottenham Court Road ">Tottenham Court Road </option>
                <option value="Tunbridge Wells ">Tunbridge Wells </option>
                <option value="Twickenham ">Twickenham </option>
                <option value="Uxbridge ">Uxbridge </option>
                <option value="Victoria ">Victoria </option>
                <option value="Walthamstow ">Walthamstow </option>
                <option value="Walworth Road ">Walworth Road </option>
                <option value="Wandsworth ">Wandsworth </option>
                <option value="Watford ">Watford </option>
                <option value="Welwyn Garden City ">Welwyn Garden City </option>
                <option value="Westminster ">Westminster </option>
                <option value="Wimbledon ">Wimbledon </option>
                <option value="Windsor ">Windsor </option>
                <option value="Wokingham ">Wokingham </option>
                <option value="Wood Green ">Wood Green </option>
                <option value="Woolwich ">Woolwich </option>
                </select>
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>

                </td>
                <td>
                <input type="hidden" id="STORE_EMAIL_FIELD" name="STORE_EMAIL_FIELD" value="">
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>

                </td>
                <td>
                <input type="hidden" id="WEB_HOME_FIELD" name="WEB_HOME_FIELD" value="">
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>

                </td>
                <td>
                <input type="hidden" id="SOURCE_FIELD" name="SOURCE_FIELD" value="St Petes">
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>
                Opt in to marketing emails
                </td>
                <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="OPTIN_FIELD" name="OPTIN_FIELD" value="true">
                </td>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td style="border:1px solid red">
                    <img id="captcha" src="/maininc/securimage/securimage_show.php" alt="CAPTCHA Image" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <input type="text" name="captcha_code" size="10" maxlength="6" />
                <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('captcha').src = '/maininc/securimage/securimage_show.php?' + Math.random(); return false">[ Different Image ]</a>

                    </td>
                </tr>



                <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center">
                <input type="button" value="Submit Form" onClick="javascript:validForm();">
                </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                </form>
                </body>
                </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by "validate CAPTCHA without leaving the form"? You have to submit the form for the data to be sent to the server, anyway, so just validate it then. You could add some kid of pre-validation to ensure the right answer is supplied, however any determined spammer will be able to remove your client-side validation. You must do server-side validation to get any of the benefit that CAPTCHA provides.

Do you have CAPTCHA image production working? The big deal behind CAPTCHA is that one has to generate images of words or numbers mostly readable to humans but difficult for computer OCR, and then be able to validate that user-supplied input matches those images. It's not something you're going to be able to do yourself if you're new to the field.

If you don't already have CAPTCHA images being produced, search online for [CAPTCHA service](https://www.google.com/search?q=captcha+service) providers. There are even some free ones like [captchas.net](http://captchas.net/) (though I cannot vouch for their quality or reliability).

Also, I would like to add that there are measures you can take to reduce or eliminate spam that don't involve CAPTCHA:

- Make sure the form was presented with a hidden field that contains a value specific to the current session. The auto-spammer will have to scrape your form.
- Set a cookie for a short interval and see if it is gone. If it's not, then it's not a real user at a real browser.
- Set a cookie for a subdomain then see if you can access it from another subdomain of the same top-level domain. If you can, then it's not a real browsing user.
- Make javascript perform some fairly complicated calculation (that you already know the correct answer to) and have it submit the answer in a hidden form field. If you vary the calculation and the code that runs, it could be very hard for someone to automate against your site.
- Rate limit connection attempts to your site. In particular, if someone requests a form that will take at minimum one minute to fill out, don't accept posts under a minute.
- Actually, for all the previous ideas, instead of blocking the spammer, instead, accept their post but if it is classified as not-a-real-browser or spam, then *only* show it to the originating IP address/user. He may not realize that the post isn't showing to others and this lack of feedback will hamper his efforts to spam your site.
- Supply five submit buttons, but use CSS to hide all but one of them. Make sure you get the right one clicked on--and make it have some code that is different each time the form is requested. The spammer will have to parse CSS rules to find out which one is showing.
- Slowly rotate the form target, the form name, form element names, and some basic html structure of your site (in a way that does not change the final result). If you rotate too fast, the spammer will figure out what you're doing. If your rotation is only every few days, the spammer will successfully script your site (presuming he gets over the other hurdles) then will move on. But then you switch everything around and his script breaks.
- Present a form, but then use ajax once a minute to get a new hidden form value. Don't just return a value, but return javascript that runs to update the form. The enterprising auto-spammer will be forced to parse JSON or javascript to figure out how to get the form to submit the right value at the right time. Of course on the server side you will expect the form to have the correct value for the time it is submitted.
- Use javascript to record controls receiving focus. Make the user click into each form field he wants to submit, in order to be successful. A user whose browser saved his incomplete form data may be inconvenienced, but people who use the site normally and just enter data in the form then submit will not be.
- Look for valid request headers that would be left out by non-browser scripting. Apply a higher standard of form validation (such as captcha) when the request headers don't make sense.
- Use redirects to make sure the spammer must support them.
- All in all, do anything and everything that can raise the bar so that custom code trying to spam your site will run into problems. You may have to take special steps to preserve usability for your real users, but I believe it can be done.

P.S. The email address validation in your question is not good. It will prevent many completely valid characters from being used. For example, the name part of the address should allow much more than letters and numbers. In particular, `+` is a valid character and one *many* people use. Do not do that to your users.

Comment: THank you alot of food for thought... Thank you for taking the time to review this.

Answer (score 1):

Validating a captcha *is not done client-side* for several, good reasons:

1. Clients can disabple JS
2. Any code you send to the client can be seen by the user, so it won't take long for bots to get the captcha contents and spam your site
3. JS validation alone is *never* enough

If the code you pasted is actually what the company "sells", look for another supplier (it's bad code, honestly).
The only thing you could do to validate the captcha without submitting the form is send an AJAX request, but be careful! This means that bots can just try random strings at will, each time sending a request and getting immediate feedback without having to send any other data than the captcha.

Yes, captcha's are annoying, and bothersome and yes they ruin the user experience and yes they can enrage us all, but they are a necessary evil. Just leave the captcha as it is, send it with the form and hope your users can figure them out.

Comment: thank you very much, we will change e-mail suppliers soon , thank you for your time answering this.

Comment: How is a form submit different to an AJAX request? A form submit is just another http request with a specialised http method (POST) and a list of the form keys and values. It is no less susceptible to bots trying random strings, right?

Comment: @poshest in and of itself, a request is a request. The difference with an HTML form submission is that with AJAX, you can prevent the default action for a form submission (which is to redirect to the action URI), meaning: you'll stay on the same page. Nothing can stop bots from spamming as such, which is exactly why I warned against validating the captcha with an AJAX request